# Selenium C#: Not able to identify xpath with class name

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to click on the highlighted record on result set window. I used the xpath as

```
""//div[contains(@class, 'email-icon icon')]/label[contains(@class, 'text')]";"
```

But,script is not able identify the record.

Note:Div id is dynamic.

Element: Record marked with blue color in screen shot.

Xpath used: "//div[contains(@class, 'email-icon icon')]/label[contains(@class, 'text')]";

HTML code:

**Dhanaprabhu0106**

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] question with more reasonable code (not half a string) and convert your image into text.

Comment: Did you check the correctness of the first part selecting a div?

Comment: @JeroenHeier yes. all div id are dynamic.  I just need to check whether the marked text "Dhanaprabhy0106" is available and click on the same.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov am sorry for the inconvenience caused. Please check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Webdriver was not able to reach to the required label using xpath you had used. Try following:

```
//div[starts-with(@id, 'sc')]//div[@class='sc-view sc-table-row-view sc-collection-item even hover sc-regular-size']/div/img[@class='email-icon icon']/following-sibling::label[normalize-space(text())='Dhanaprabhu0106']
```

Let me know, whether it works for you.

**Update 1:**

Try to click using IJavaScriptExecutor, as shown below:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor e = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
e.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'sc')]//div[@class='sc-view sc-table-row-view sc-collection-item even hover sc-regular-size']/div/img[@class='email-icon icon']/following-sibling::label[normalize-space(text())='Dhanaprabhu0106']"));
```

Let me know, whether it works for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mahipal.It highlights the record. Updated the xpath as  "//div[starts-with(@id, 'sc')]//div[@class='sc-view sc-table-row-view sc-collection-item even sc-regular-size']/div/img[@class='email-icon icon']/following-sibling::label[contains(@class, 'text')]" and passing it to click a event. But, element is not clicked.

Comment: I am sorry for the delayed response. It takes me to the details page.

Comment: Refer to 'Update 1:' in my answer above and let me know, whether it works for you.

Comment: element itself is not identified now.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is incorrect. See my examples below.

```
//div[contains(@class, 'has-icon')]/label[contains(@class, 'text')]"
```

or

```
//img[contains(@class, 'email-icon')]/../label[contains(@class, 'text')]"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Buaban. The above mentioned xpath highlights the entire row and not clicking on the particular element.

Comment: @Dhanaprabhu which is the element that you want to click?

Comment: I wanted to click "Dhanaprabhu0106" and your xpath is working. Thanks a lot for your timely help.